# I'm trying to generate 7 random scrabble characters, but I'm getting more than 7 values stored

Tags: c

```
//This program is a basic scrabble game with some error checking.
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define num_letters 7
#define tiles_max 100
//value 1 and 2 are the same, they were passed from a generate letter set if statement to determine the max
//value of things to add up
int sum_array (int value1, int letter_set[], int value2, int tile_set[]){
  int counter2, sum_of_array;
  sum_of_array = 0;
  for(counter2 = 0; counter2 < value1; counter2++){
    sum_of_array += tile_set[counter2] - letter_set[counter2];
  }
  return sum_of_array;
}

void generate_letter_set (int letter_set[], int size_letter_set, int lettersbgood){
  const int tile_set[] = {9, 2, 2, 4, 12, 2, 3, 2, 9, 1, 1, 4, 2, 6, 8, 2, 1, 6, 4, 6, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2};
  int counter1, counter3, chargen;
  srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
  for(counter1 = 0; counter1 < lettersbgood; counter1++){
    chargen = rand() % (tiles_max - counter1);
    for(counter3 = 0; counter3 < 27; counter3++){
      if(chargen >= sum_array(counter3, letter_set, counter3, tile_set) && chargen < (sum_array(counter3, letter_set, counter3, tile_set)+(tile_set[counter3]-letter_set[counter3]))){
    letter_set[counter3] += 1;
      }
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  int size_letter_set = 27, counter4;
  int letter_set[27] = {0};
  printf("This program plays a game of scrabble.\n");
  generate_letter_set(letter_set, size_letter_set, num_letters);
  printf("Your letters are: \n");
  for(counter4 = 0; counter4 < size_letter_set; counter4++){
    printf("%d ", letter_set[counter4]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I am expecting it to print out at most 7 nonzero characters adding up to 7 and at least 1 nonzero character adding up to 7 and the rest as zeroes.

What I get instead is various numbers of nonzero characters totaling more than 7.

Sample output: 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
Sometimes there are 2's or 3's as well. This program uses the c99 standard.

I'd like to know why it's producing too many inputs (I think it's going through the loop too many times). Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: first of all, read something about clean code - yours is VERY hard to read. Secondly, use a real editor (like Visual Studio Code) and refactor this - names like i,j,k are MUCH more readable for loop counters. Then, try to explain in comments in code what each line does - if your code is clean, it is self explenatory. Answer questions like: why do I set chargen (change that name too) like that? Why is there constant 27 as a loop limit limit? Why 27? Maybe it is not constant? Size_letter_set has the same value, coincidence? If you use the same nubmer for the same meaning, use #define

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is using `tiles_max` with a value of 100 in the modulo to get an index into an array of [27]. This simplifies the selection.

```
//This program is a basic scrabble game with some error checking.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_LETTERS 7
#define LETTER_SET 27

void generate_letter_set (int letter_set[], int lettersbgood){
    const int tile_set[LETTER_SET] = {9, 2, 2, 4, 12, 2, 3, 2, 9, 1, 1, 4, 2, 6, 8, 2, 1, 6, 4, 6, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2};
    int counter1, chargen;

    counter1 = lettersbgood;
    do {
        chargen = rand() % (LETTER_SET);
        if ( tile_set[chargen] > letter_set[chargen]){
            letter_set[chargen] += 1;
            counter1--;
            printf("%d\n", letter_set[chargen]);
        }
    } while ( counter1);
}

int main()
{
    int counter4;
    int letter_set[LETTER_SET] = {0};

    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    printf("This program plays a game of scrabble.\n");
    generate_letter_set(letter_set, NUM_LETTERS);
    printf("Your letters are: \n");
    for(counter4 = 0; counter4 < LETTER_SET; counter4++){
        printf("%d ", letter_set[counter4]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. It took me a bit to figure out why the 27 vs 100 array size issue mattered, but that showed me the right path. Krzysztof Skowronek, I am sorry for not formatting it better. I'm a new programmer and I was trying to rush.